# Extract text between HTML tags

Tags: vbscript, sed, text-files, command-line-tool

I have many HTML files from which I need to extract text. If it's all on one line, I can do that quite easily but if the tag wraps around or is on multiple lines I can't figure how to do this. Here's what I mean:

```
<section id="MySection">
Some text here
another line here <br>
last line of text.
</section>
```

I'm not concerned about the `<br>` text, unless it will help wrap the text around. The area that I want always begins with "MySection" and then is ended with `</section>`. What I'd like to end up with is something like this:

```
Some text here  another line here  last line of text.
```

I'd prefer something like a vbscript or command line option (sed?) but I'm not sure where to begin. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you'd use the Internet Explorer COM object for this:

```
root = "C:\base\dir"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(root).Files
  ie.Navigate "file:///" & f.Path
  While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

  text = ie.document.getElementById("MySection").innerText

  WScript.Echo Replace(text, vbNewLine, "")
Next
```

However, the `<section>` tag is not supported prior to IE 9, and even in IE 9 the COM object doesn't seem to handle it correctly, as `getElementById("MySection")` only returns the opening tag:

```
>>> wsh.echo ie.document.getelementbyid("MySection").outerhtml
<SECTION id=MySection>
```

You could use a regular expression instead, though:

```
root = "C:\base\dir"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set re1 = New RegExp
re1.Pattern = "<section id=""MySection"">([\s\S]*?)</section>"
re1.Global  = False
re2.IgnoreCase = True

Set re2 = New RegExp
re2.Pattern = "(<br>|\s)+"
re2.Global  = True
re2.IgnoreCase = True

For Each f In fso.GetFolder(root).Files
  html = fso.OpenTextFile(filename).ReadAll

  Set m = re1.Execute(html)
  If m.Count > 0 Then
    text = Trim(re2.Replace(m.SubMatches(0).Value, " "))
  End If

  WScript.Echo text
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a one-liner solution using `perl` and a HTML parser from `Mojolicious` framework:

```
perl -MMojo::DOM -E '
    say Mojo::DOM->new( do { undef $/; <> } )->at( q|#MySection| )->text
' index.html
```

Assuming `index.html` with following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body id="portada">
<section id="MySection">
Some text here
another line here <br>
last line of text.
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

It yields:

```
Some text here another line here last line of text.
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a proper parser and the overall elegant solution.