# how to omit special characters with spaces with sed in website?

Tags: sed

Hi I am new using "sed" I need display text, between special characters and spaces with a bash script. Exist "similar" questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629228/extract-text-between-html-tags) but doesn't work for me, because I will use the variable in a bash script. I need help with "sed" not "perl" I have no a index.html locally. also I am using Linux.

This is my variable:

```
output="$(wget -q http://software.opensuse.org/package/clementine -O - | sed -ne '/<p id="pkg-desc">/, /[.</p>]$/p')"
```

echo $output

```
<p id="pkg-desc">Clementine is a modern music player and library organiser. Clementine is a port of Amarok 1.4, with some features rewritten to take advantage of Qt4.
```

Exist other alternative with sed about how to display text between `<p id="pkg-desc">`some text.`</p>` ? or how to delete `<p id="pkg-desc">` in my variable?

sorry my english is bad :/

Comment: Hi all, I solved it with part of an answer deleted: `output=$(wget -q http://software.opensuse.org/package/clementine -O - | sed -ne '/pkg-desc">/,/[.</p>]$/p' | sed 's#<p id="pkg-desc">##g')`

Comment: That is not correct. `[.</p>]$` requires that the character just before end of string is one of `.` or `<` or `/` etc; nothing more and borhing less.

Comment: @tripleee correctly, but if  I do not include the "." Sed extracts a large text, I do not want it. `[</p>]` is repeated in all site. Then I delimited finishing in `[.</p>]$` .

Comment: Thanks all for the negative... read the linked question doesn't have solutions with my question, sorry but I have reason. I will not change my posture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an  `gnu awk` version

```
output=$(wget -q software.opensuse.org/package/clementine -O - | awk -v RS='<p id="pkg-desc">' -F"</p>" 'NR==2{print $1}')
echo "$output"
Clementine is a modern music player and library organiser. Clementine is a
port of Amarok 1.4, with some features rewritten to take advantage of Qt4.

Features:

    * Search and play your local music library
    * Listen to internet radio from Last.fm and SomaFM
    * Edit tags on MP3 and OGG files, organise your music
    * Cross-platform - works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux
    * Native desktop notifications on Linux (libnotify) and Mac OS X (Growl)
```

Comment: thanks also worked! but also need enclosed with double quote. without double quote doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
output="$(wget -q software.opensuse.org/package/clementine -O - | sed -ne 's|<p id=\"pkg-desc\">\(.*\)</p>$|\1|p')"
```

- escpae `"` due to `output="`
- use `|` as sed separator instead of `/` due to presence of this char inside the string to find (easier to manage)
- use a `s///` and not an adress finding `//,//` due to internal content (only) to print

Comment: sorry but doesn't work "sed:-e expression # 1, character 37: sequence `s' unfinished"

Comment: sorry, i change the / to | and copy older version with still /. Reply is OK now

Comment: mmm now doesn't display none :/

Comment: that means that pattern is not found or no content inside delimiter. Do you have a sample of output from your `wget`

Comment: Ok, see my pastebin http://pastebin.com/raFLffW6