# Extract and use a variable from a part of curl output string

Tags: html, curl

I need to run the following curl command (e.g. a POST request), where '**XXXX**' is a 10-digit number that changes

```
curl "https://foo.com/_mycart?ts=XXXX" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:65.0) ..."
```

I thus have to retrieve this number, and to do that I use this command (to get the URL re-direct):

```
curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} http://google.com
```

This then returns a block of HTML, where one part contains the dynamic number ("XXXX") I need to grab/retrieve:

```
<script>
        window.location='https://foo.com/_mycart?fn=reference&ts=XXXX';
</script>
```

I thus need to retrieve the value of **'XXXX'** and then use it in the curl command aforementioned:

```
curl "https://foo.com/_mycart?ts=XXXX" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:65.0) ... "
```

Hence, what's the best way to store '**XXXX**' into a variable and use it in the above command (where 'XXXX' is above)?

Ideally, is it then possible to run all of this in a single command? e.g. using | ?

Thanks so much for your help - I have searched but I am new to curl and not that great at HTML, and just trying to get some efficiency.

Just to clarify, is there a solution that can be done in the Windows command prompt, or another solution without being too complex (e.g. having to know another programming language)?

Comment: You could use regex in some language, javascript, asp, php .. etc. it would be easier to strip html code, then parse the url.

Comment: Thanks Dohab - what would you recommend to use in this scenario? I was trying to keep it as vanilla as possible through the use of the Windows command prompt

Comment: Since you use windows, go with vbscript or perl. Personally I prefer perl in this situation. [Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629228/extract-text-between-html-tags)