# Similar regular expression in same line

Tags: regex

I have requirement of following reg-ex pattern:

Sample string :

```
<html> a test of  strength and <h1> valour </h1> for <<<NOT>>> faint hearted <b> BUT </b> protoganist having their characters <<<CARVED>>> out of gibralter <b> ROCK </b>
```

This above is single string in which I want to strip out every `HTML tag` and retain `<<<xyz>>>` .

My attempt:

```regex
(^|\n| )<[^>]*>(\n| |$)
```

Can someone please critically review this ?

Comment: Have you considered using an HTML parser? It would make this task trivial. If you have a good reason not to, please tell us which environment (language, tool) you're running your regex in, as possible solutions will depend on that

Comment: No, I have not considered it as am un-aware of it. My language is vbscript/vba . Any references for HTML Parser using vbscript ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with vbscript, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629228/extract-text-between-html-tags) seems to address that topic well

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Obligatory [parsing HTML with RegEx warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1014587).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've come up with. It uses [lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure you identify hmtl tags by what will precede and follow them without actually including them in the match. The point is to look for `<` and `>` only if they are followed or preceded by spaces or letters (not other `<` or `>`). Is this what you are after or did I misread you?

```
(?=([ A-z]?))<{1}\/?[A-z1-6]+>{1}(?=[^>])
```

Comment: It's because the last `</b>` ended the string. I made an edit to address this. My apologies.

Comment: Made final modification as follows
` (?=([ A-z]?))<{1}\/?[A-z1-6]+>{1}(?=[ A-z]|$) `